# How to combine two activities together to use it as a single feature?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, tablayout

I am stuck with a problem where I have designed a tab layout that I have used as a library in the current project which has a Recycler View. I want to show the tab layout on top and the recycler view under the tab layout.
For reference in Whatsapp, there is tab layout under which there is a recycler view that shows all the messages.
Problem is that I am confused about how to combine both activities together so the user can use the tab layout.
If anyone knows any solution please help!!

Comment: You can't, use fragments instead

Comment: see this link for reference of creating tablayout in android : https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view

Answer (score 1):

Use **single-activity** pattern. This pattern means that you need to use Fragments in a single activity (MainActivity, etc). Additional tip, you can use ViewPager2 with TabLayout for your Fragments.

Activities can't be composed into one, cause it designed so.